# SwiftUI - Layouts gone wild after latest Xcode update

Tags: layout, swiftui, swift5, xcode11.4

After I updated the Xcode to 11.4 (11E146), all of my views has expanded vertically and does not fit the screen. It was all working fine before the update. The problem is happening in the `Preview` and `Simulator`. It is same whether the view has navigation or not, Here is an example

[image]

Anyone had the same problem and got any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the below `View Modifier` from `TabView` fixed it.

```
.edgeIngoringSafeArea(.top)
```